# Noise++ Perlin Module returns 0 all the time

Tags: c++, perlin-noise, noise-generator

Im using the Noise++ Library to generate noise in my program, well at least thats the aim.
I have it setup like one of the tests in order to test it out, however no matter what parameters I give it I only get 0 back

If anyone has any experience with Noise++ it would be really helpful if you could check over and see if im doing anything wrong.

```
//
// Defaults are
// Frequency    =   1
// Octaves      =   6
// Seed         =   0
// Quality      =   1
// Lacunarity   =   2
// Persistence  =   0.5
// Scale        =   2.12
//

NoiseppNoise::NoiseppNoise( ) : mPipeline2d( 2 )
{
    mThreadCount = noisepp::utils::System::getNumberOfCPUs ();

    mPerlin.setSeed(4321);
    if ( mThreadCount > 2 ) {
        mPipeline2d = noisepp::ThreadedPipeline2D( mThreadCount );
    }

    mNoiseID2D = mPerlin.addToPipe ( mPipeline2d );
    mCache2d = mPipeline2d.createCache();
}

double NoiseppNoise::Generate( double x, double y )
{
    return mPipeline2d.getElement( mNoiseID2D )->getValue ( x, y, mCache2d );
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you wait for threads to complete?

Comment: I thought the threading was all done internally, ie: the user (in this case me) doesnt have to worry about threading issues

Comment: Does it work if you don't use threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the following lines to your code to compile (basically no changes except for cleaning the cache):

```
struct NoiseppNoise
{
  NoiseppNoise();
  double Generate( double x, double y );

  noisepp::ThreadedPipeline2D mPipeline2d;
  noisepp::ElementID mThreadCount;
  noisepp::PerlinModule mPerlin;
  noisepp::ElementID mNoiseID2D;
  noisepp::Cache*  mCache2d;
};

/* constructor as in the question */

double NoiseppNoise::Generate( double x, double y )
{
  mPipeline2d.cleanCache (mCache2d);  // clean the cache before calculating value
  return mPipeline2d.getElement( mNoiseID2D )->getValue ( x, y, mCache2d );
}
```

Calling it with

```
NoiseppNoise np;
std::cout<<np.Generate(1.5,1)<<std::endl;
```

actually outputs a good value, 0.0909 for me.

However if you call it with two "integers" (e.g. 3.0 and 5.0) the output will be 0 because at some point something similar to the following statement is executed:

```
const Real xs = Math::CubicCurve3 (x - Real(x0));
```

If the parameters are integers then `x` and `Real(x0)` are always the same because `Real(x0)` is basically the integer part of `x` and so `xs` will be set to 0. After this there are more calculations to get the actual value but it becomes deterministically 0.